# Using cURL & OpenSSL to thoroughly test certificate validity of all websites

Tags: bash, ssl, curl, openssl

I have a large number of websites I need to test the SSL/TLS setups for.  Some tests I need to perform are:

- Is the server cert expired?
- Is old encryption (i.e. SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS 1.0) being used?
- Is the cert chain missing any intermediate certificates?  If so, which one(s)?
- Is the root certificate of the chain expired?

I feel like this is doable with Bash, cURL, and maybe OpenSSL.  I've done some testing with cURL but interpreting the output is confusing in some cases.  Also, I've been unable to use any of these methods to detect if the root cert of the chain is expired, which is a common problem I'm trying to chase down.

Example:

```
curl -v --cert-status https://someserver.somedomain.com/

*   Trying xx.yy.zz.aa:443...
* Connected to someserver.somedomain.com (xx.yy.zz.aa) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.**
```

This is a server that's known to be missing an intermediate certificate.  Can I safely deduce that from the `"TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560)" or "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"` line?  If so, can I use this output to determine which intermediate cert is missing?

Also, the above method doesn't seem to tell me when a root cert of the chain is expired unless it's buried somewhere.

Comment: An interesting problem, but not  really an `if/then/else` programming code problem (as presented). Please note that [mcve] is the rule of thumb for a good question here on S.O. Without copy/pasteable code, these are very open-ended questions. If possible, can you set up a local server in a test environment , start out with an known expired root certificate, if you can't resolve that, then post a new question with just that issue. Same for the rest of your list, incremental testing in a controlled  environment, then each step validate against your production servers. Good luck!

Comment: (But I will be happy if someone does give more specific advice/solutions).

Comment: the openssl method below looks like the right approach. It seems to pull all certs at once, and errors out if a cert is missing. That gets me much closer to what need to know.

Comment: Seems you have got some useful help here and you have been working on your problem yourself, so ++!  (but this would have been a better fit on [unix.se]). If you get a fully working script, be sure to post it and accept it after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Meta: this isn't really programming or development, but I don't see any votes against yet, and I need extensive formatting. I will delete this if ncessary.

Asides: checking for expiration is not at all the same as 'thoroughly test[ing] validity' of a certificate, and checking for a website isn't always the same as other SSL/TLS applications. There are *many* other conditions that must be met for certificate validity; `openssl` and `curl` using OpenSSL (as your build does, but not all do), checks *some* of these but not others. `curl` checks for website/host name (given an https URL), but `openssl s_client` doesn't do so by default because OpenSSL can be used for many other applications besides web/HTTPS and some don't handle hostname the same or don't even *have* a hostname.

In addition to basic chaining (signatures, AKI=SKI if present, BasicConstraints, and KeyUsage) and NameConstraints, openssl does check expiration for all certs in a chain including the root (which isn't officially required by RFC5280, but is common). OTOH if you are using a truststore that tracks one of the major 'root-cert' programs (Microsoft/Windows, Apple, Google/Android, Java, Mozilla) they generally remove expired roots entirely, so using a root that in fact exists and is expired will usually show up on the client as *unknown-not-trusted* root not expired root.

For now there is one easy-to-demonstrate and convenient case: LetsEncrypt is [still using a 'cross' cert aka bridge](https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility.html) to the expired Identrust/Trustid/DST X3 root (although they [plan to stop soon](https://letsencrypt.org/2023/07/10/cross-sign-expiration.html)) and Stack uses LE. Nearly all modern devices ignore this cross cert and substitute the (NON-expired) ISRG Root X1 cert at least, and possibly ISRG Root X2, allowing the cert to validate successfully, but with openssl (or curl/openssl) you can force a case which does use it:

```
openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 <NUL -CAfile trustid.DSTRoot3.pem
CONNECTED(000001C4)
depth=4 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:1
depth=4 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:1
depth=3 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
notAfter=Sep 30 18:14:03 2024 GMT
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X2
notAfter=Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
notAfter=Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = stackoverflow.com
notAfter=Feb 14 15:32:32 2024 GMT
verify return:1
---
[rest snipped except for]
Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
---
```

(`s_client` is a test tool that ignores cert validation errors and continues with the connection anyway, but it does *display* the error(s) as shown. Example shown is 1.1.1; for 1.1.0 down many servers, including Stack-which-is-really-Cloudflare, require specifying `-servername $host`, and at least for me the callback display stops at the error point.)

In contrast if I use an up-to-date-ish truststore -- which includes ISRG X1 *and* X2, but not DST X3 -- it uses the non-expired X2 root and is joyously happy:

```
c:\work>openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 <NUL -CAfile (curlMoz)cacert-2023-01-10.pem
CONNECTED(000001AC)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = stackoverflow.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = stackoverflow.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = E1
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X2
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X2
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
 3 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
...
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

(The second display is a summary -- subject and issuer names only -- of the chain *as received* from the server as opposed to the one validated; this shows that the server is still sending the X2-cross-to-X1 and X1-cross-to-DST certs as in the case above, but now `s_client` is discarding them and using the X2 root.)

Comment: Dave, you hit upon one of the major use cases I'm trying to ferret out:  those expired DST X3 certs.  They're scattered all over and I need to find them and deal with them before they become a bigger problem.  Thank you for this!

Comment: What did you use to generate the .pem files you're feeding into the -CAfile argument?

Comment: (0) DST X3 should _already_ be removed from and ignored by nearly all clients, and for servers using LetsEncrypt it will disappear automatically in a few months as explained in the second page I linked. (1) `(curlMoz)cacert*` is the Mozilla root store reformatted into seq-PEM-cert (convenient for `openssl` and many other things that use OpenSSL) [by the curl project](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html). I don't bother updating frequently and the version I have is not the latest, but it is recent enough to include ISRG X1 and X2 and exclude DST X3 (which was removed back in 2021). ...

Comment: ... (2) `DSTRoot3` is the DST X3 cert downloaded (in PEM) using the link in https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/ -- but I happen to have old versions of the curl/Mozilla 'bundle' and the Oracle (and Sun) Java 'cacerts' archived and I verified this 'new' file is actually the same as the DST X3 root that was actively used (and valid) for many years before 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Using `openssl` might help you

```
openssl s_client -connect server:port -showcerts
```

This way you can download certificates and then process certificates to get the information you're trying to get

Comment: This command leads to error `s_client: must not provide both -connect option and target parameter`.
Did try it before suggesting?

Comment: If you restructure his suggestion to this:

openssl s_client -connect server:port -showcerts 2>&1 < /dev/null

Then it works as intended.  This doesn't answer all my questions, but it gets me closer by showing me a way to pull all the certs at once.  It has the handy side effect of erroring out if it can't pull one or more cert, which (I think) can be a way to detect missing intermediate certs.

Comment: This trick may work in case when there is only one web server on the host otherwise the comand hangs up,

Comment: For checking certificate chain you can use `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect host:port | openssl openssl verify -CAfile - `